# The value of the local variable "img" is not used

Tags: processing, kinect

I'm running the coding trains tutorials right now. but when following his instructions I keep getting an error. can somebody show me what is wrong with my code?

```java
import org.openkinect.processing.*;

Kinect kinect;

void setup() {

    PImage img; 

    size(512, 484); 
    kinect = new Kinect(this); 
    kinect.initDepth(); 
    img = createImage(kinect.width, kinect.height, RGB); 

}  

void draw() { 
    background(0); 

    img.loadPixels(); 

    int[] depth = kinect.getRawDepth(); 

    for (int x = 0; x < kinect.width; x++) { 
        for (int y = 0; y < kinect.height; y++) {
            int offsett = x + y * kinect.width; 
            int d = depth[offsett]; 

            img.pixels[offset] = color(255,0,150);
        }
    }

    img.updatePixels(); 
    image(img, 0, 0);
}
```

thank you for your help!

Comment: Things defined in functions stay in those functions. If you need a global variable `img`, define it globally, outside of `setup`, like you've already done with `kinect`.

Answer (score 1):

You defined the variable img in the setup() function, so the scope of that variable is only that method.

You use several times a variable img in the draw() function, but you never defined one inside that function.

I would say that the error is the confusion of having the same variable name in both functions.

Comment: thank you , the "setup img" was in the wrong place. its supposed to come before setup!

Answer (score -2):

Try to change the name of same variables, its not a good approach and maybe this is reason of error.